# Entity delete fails due to FK

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working with ef6.
I have 2 entities:

```
House
{
List<Person> Persons
}

Person
{
House House
Nullable<int> HouseId
}
```

I am trying to delete the house entity without deleting the persons that live in the house this way:

```
public void DeleteHouse(House house)
{
    foreach( var person in house.Persons)
    {
       person.House = null;
    }

    house.Persons = null;
 context.Houses.Attach(house);
 context.Houses.Remove(house)
}
```

I get:

The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Tx

Comment: What is the datatype on HouseId?

Comment: it is Nullable<int>

Comment: Do you have any fluent configuration of your model?  Assuming you're working code-first here.

Comment: Have you tried `person.HouseId = null;`

Comment: The conventions *should* support what you're doing here, but that is always a grey area for me.  Even when followed, I prefer to specify and remove all doubt should the model get more complicated.  Do you have "real" code for `Person` and `House` to beef up the pseudocode?  Have you checked the database?  Is the `HouseId` column nullable there?  Check that there isn't a `House_HouseId` column.

Comment: The more I'm looking at this, the more I think we need to see more code.

Comment: I work with sql first.  The system is stand alone,  so i cant copy the code to the internet. I have tried Houseid= null.